# what does the following java script expression mean

Tags: javascript, regex, string-matching

I was going through a piece of code and I hit against this syntax

```
str.replace(re,function(raw, p1, p2, p3){
  if (!/\/\//.test(p1)) {  // <---- this one
    //some more code
  }
});
```

I understand that the test method matches one string with another, and checks if it is present. But what does this regex `/\/\//` matching the string to?
I checked the regex, and

`\/ matches the character / literally 
\/ matches the character / literally`

so what does `if(!//.test(p1))` doing?

Comment: if(!//.test(p1)), is matching everything different of nothing. // surround your regex, so /\/\// mean regex matching of \/\/, you need to escape / with \. So finally /\/\// will match with 2/ consecutive like : //toto

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conditional is true if the string does not contain two consecutive slashes.

Answer (score 1):

If first captured group  `()` `p1` contains `//` return `false` at `if` condition by converting `true` to `false` using `!` operator

Comment: @ClasG _"There aren't any capture groups involved here."_ ? `p1` should be first capture group at `RegExp`?

Comment: I "removed" down vote - I focused on the question "so what does if(!//.test(p1)) doing?" - didn't see the whole picture

Comment: @ClasG The condition can return either `true` or `false` `!/\/\//.test("//")`

Answer (score 1):

`\/` matches the character `/` literally. The above regex will execute if condition if there are no 2 consecutive `/`.
check out this: [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/60w7tzvy/)